# How to get contact number from alexa voice profile or amazon account for developing alexa skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

As in alexa developer portal, in the permission section, there is a permission for the contact number. How to retrieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

As specified [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html), you will need to generate a request to Amazon for user information. You've got the first step of configuring your skill to request permission for such information. Now, you will need to get the `apiAccessToken` to make a request to the Alexa Customer Profile API for account information. Examples of the request are illustrated [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html#request-example).

Be sure that you complete the [Before You Begin](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html#before-you-begin) prerequisites before sending a request!

Answer (score 0):

I have researched and come upto this point by following below steps;

1. Go to developer.amazon account where you have setup your alexa skill, under the tab "Build" you will find the left menu "Permissions" and switch on "Customer Email Address" permission.
2. Go to https://alexa.amazon.com/spa/index.html#cards -> Skills -> Your Skills -> select your skill -> Settings -> Manage Permissions -> Switch on required permission you have switched on in point 1 and save
3. in the java code inside your intent handler `@Override
   public Optional<Response> handle(HandlerInput input) {
       UpsServiceClient upsServiceClient = input.getServiceClientFactory().getUpsService().getProfileEmail();
   }`